# Show/mark not visible labels (colliding labels)

Tags: qgis, labeling

If "show all labels, also colliding" is not active, some colliding labels will not show up. So far so good, but I would like to know, how often and where this happens and maybe why. Something like a red dot where the invisible label is, would satisfy me. Any ideas?

Comment: I really would like to have the same functionnality ... in any case QGIS is able to detect these cases but what next ... what would u like with that ? treat these special cases by yourself ? without generating other collision ofc ...

Comment: Sadly, QGIS 3.10 has discontinued functionality for "show colliding labels." Even if this box is checked, it no longer shows colliding labels. This destroys many valuable uses for QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is being introduced in QGIS 3.10 (and is currently available in the "nightly" beta releases)