# How to show labels on all contour lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

I want to label the contour lines in my project, but for some reason the elevations from 1820 to 1920 don't show. They are all from the same layer and is it Single labels, not Rule-based labels. Also, the field used for labelling (ELEV) does exist in those line 1820 to 1920 and is correctly filled.

[image]

I tried to change the overlapping settings in `Layer properties / Labels / Rendering` to no effect, as described in this question: [Show all contour line labels in Layout in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350899/show-all-contour-line-labels-in-layout-in-qgis)

One solution would be to manually add the missing values in the print layout before exporting but I am looking for a better way to fix this.